# Prepending text to a specific column in a tab-delimited file?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file like this (tab delimited), but many lines

```
1314    0   0   0   0   0   3   1321    -   k63_1878003 1314    0   1314    6   171115067   64288422    64291057    4   12,131,75,1096, 0,12,143,218,   64288422,64288802,64289161,64289961,
```

I need to prepend a `string` to column 14 of each line but keep everything else the same. Can I do this in awk or would it be better in sed?

Comment: Column, as in space-separated?  Or before the 14th character?

Comment: What is the column delimiter? Or, are columns fixed widths (and what widths?) It looks like both space (or tab) and comma may be in use. Also, what string are your prepending?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `awk`. `OFS` prints a tab between fields in output:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $14 = "string" $14; print }' infile
```

Comment: +1 You can shorten it to: `awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } $14 = "string" $14' infile` since the assignment is "true" and "true" defaults to printing `$0`.

Comment: You get a point because you specified to set the OFS, I am not so great with awk so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file.txt | sed 's/\(\([^\t]\+\t\)\{13\}\)/\1string/g'
```

In other words: replace `(([^ ] +){13})` (thirteen non-tab chunks followed by tabs) with that same text, plus your `string`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more elegant than this `awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11"\t"$12"\t"$13"\t""string"$14"\t"$15"\t"$16"\t"$17"\t"$18"\t"$19"\t"$20"\t"$21}'` haha. Also thanks for not asking what string I am using, knowing that it is a completely irrelevant question.

Comment: Haha no problem.  Yeah, looking at the other answers, it does seem like `awk` is more appropriate for this, but I don't really know how to use it yet... so `sed` it is. :P

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^\t]*/string&/14' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation to append to a field in AWK. For example:

```
$ echo "foo bar baz" | awk -vOFS=$'\t' '$2 = "quux" $2'
foo quuxbar baz
```

In your case, you would obviously use field $13 instead. By making changes in the pattern portion, rather than the action, you are just replacing the value of the field and using the default print action for the line.

Comment: @Dan That's because you don't have your OFS set right. When $0 is split, you usually need to specify OFS explicitly for tab-delimiters. You can do this with the -v flag, or by setting OFS in a BEGIN block.  --I've updated the example to show how to fix this using the flag method.

Comment: AWK understands `\t` there's no need for the `$''`

Comment: My OFS was not set right because you did not specify I had to do so in your solution. You edited it in after I posted that comment.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Both will work; it depends on the semantics you wish to convey, and whether you want Bash or AWK to handle the character expansion. In this example, it is certainly a semantic difference, rather than a functional one. YMMV.